# How to navigate in a view - React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-listview

I don't know what should I call it but I want to do something like [**Fragment Identifier**](https://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/Fragment.html)

Infact I have one notifications page and another blog page. What I want is when I click on a specific notification, it should navigate to its corresponding article headline in blog page. At the moment, it just navigates to (start of) blog page only.

Comment: Why don't you do two navigator.push call in a row?
First to main blog page and second to specific blog page?

Comment: No, actually a blog is a page where all articles are placed. Now I want to navigate in such a way that when I click on specific notification (which is related to a specific article), app should navigate to blog page and automatically scrolls and highlight that specific article item. Got it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I build more than one routes in a single component - React Native](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38837703/how-can-i-build-more-than-one-routes-in-a-single-component-react-native)

Comment: When creating ListView you can get the ScrollView inside it (as _scrollView).
On rendering each item in the list use `onLayout` to find out place of item in the list (height from top) and save it.
Then use `_scrollView.scrollTo` to go to specific item.